# Why do I need to use many flushing functions to flush the output buffer (using wamp, PHP)

Tags: php, buffer, output-buffering

In wamp server, I cannot flush the output buffer unless I use these functions:

```
ob_end_flush();
ob_flush();
flush();
ob_start();
```

Why do I need to use all of these functions?
Why does simple `ob_flush()` is not working?
my code :

```
<?php    
ob_start();
    header( 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );
    echo 'Begin ...<br />';
    for( $i = 0 ; $i < 6 ; $i++ )
    {
        echo $i . '<br />';
        sleep(1);
        ob_end_flush();
        ob_flush();
        flush();
        ob_start();
    }
    echo 'End ...<br />';
    ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you have by default parameter [output_buffering](http://php.net/output-buffering) = on

Go to **C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\php.ini**

And find line

**output_buffering = On**

and change it to

**;output_buffering = On**

Comment: you are king! but why do I need to use "ob_flush" and "flush" together?
sorry for my english, i am from Israel.

Comment: You can find the answer [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php). It's pretty hard to answer for me, but you could just explain what is your purpose in using output buffering :>

Comment: Why do I need to delete the sentence about "output_buffering" in PHP.INI? Is there an explanation?

Comment: @Lior because it is written in the file (at least in my php.ini): ; `Note: This directive is hardcoded to Off for the CLI SAPI
; Default Value: Off`

Comment: Or you could just set the value to Off: `output_buffering = Off`

Comment: can you explain more about it?
what is CLI SAPI?
Thank you very very very much :)

Comment: for the hebrew readers, I wrote about it an article :
[link](http://www.lior-portal.co.il/blog/%D7%A4%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%A7%D7%A6%D7%99%D7%95%D7%AA-ob/)
תהנו :)

Comment: What is the purpose of using `ob_start()` which turns on **output buffering** when you turn it off in your php settings?